# Query not running in HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB for JUNIT testing.

There is a query that is not excuting in HSQL but executes with Sybase drivers.
I am using Spring JDBC to run the queries and hsqldb.1.8.1.jar file for HSQLDB.

Below is the Code:

```
public static final String ORG_CODE_QUERY = "SELECT ORG_CODE = org.name " +
         "  FROM " + ORGANIZATION  + " org " +
         " WHERE org.id   = ? " +
         "   AND org.industry = ?  ";


public List<String> getOrgCode(RequestPayload rqstPayload) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(ORG_CODE_QUERY, new Object[]{rqstPayload.getId(),rqstPayload.getIndustry()}, new ResultSetExtractor<List<String>>() {
            public List<String> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(rs.next()) {
                    list.add(rs.getString("ORG_CODE"));
                }
                return list;
            }
        });
    }
```

Spring Configuration :

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test" />
        <property name="user" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

This query runs perfectly when the Sybase datasource is passed to JDBCTemplate but fails when HSQLDB datasource is passed.

It also runs in HSQL if i change the String as below

```
public static final String ORG_CODE_QUERY = "SELECT org.name as ORG_CODE" +
         "  FROM " + ORGANIZATION  + " org " +
         " WHERE org.id   = ? " +
         "   AND org.industry = ?  ";
```

Unfortunately can't change the production Code .

I get the below error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: ORG_CODE in statement
```

Please let me know if there is turnaround for this issue.

Thanks
Avnish

Answer (score 2):

[HSQL does not support](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_sql_select_statement) the `SELECT <alias> = <column definition>` syntax that you are using in your Sybase SQL query.

You would need to either find a version of the query that works for both database systems, or include some sort of switch in your class that lets you execute the Sybase syntax when using Sybase and the HSQL syntax when using HSQL.

Comment: does the higher versions of HSQL support this query ? Tried using the HSQL 2.2.9 , but was not able to register the Driver.As per documentation the JDBC driver is org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcDriver...Thanks

Comment: I linked to the documentation of the latest HSQL version. So, no.

Comment: With 2.2.9, use the same string as before (org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver) to register the driver. The alternative is actually org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver but may not work with some third party software.